# Flutter (iOS) Firebase Auth Sign in With Phone Number: Error after adding ' pod 'Firebase/Auth' ' inside Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, authentication, podfile

I'm using the Firebase Auth Sign in with Phone Number and Register with Phone number methods. They're working fine on android but when implementing them on iOS my app crashes. After doing some digging on the Firebase Auth documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth), I'm trying to add this line inside my Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

but I'm getting a very long error involving credentials and a tag name-- which I'm struggling to identify and solve. Here's the full (repeating/ongoing) error:

```
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           60.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[73021]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f37a9160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1162242b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[73021]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f37a91b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x116224308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2021-05-04 15:44:38.156 xcodebuild[73021:905192] CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
    2021-05-04 15:44:40.458 XCBBuildService[73024:905308] Failed to remove: /Users/andrewvillegas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glrfilgccqgizafzlzobrbgaoqsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/08a4bf4e9f6e797d8eb62106a7176b83-manifest.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/andrewvillegas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glrfilgccqgizafzlzobrbgaoqsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/08a4bf4e9f6e797d8eb62106a7176b83-manifest.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    2021-05-04 15:44:40.603 XCBBuildService[73024:905308] Failed to remove: /Users/andrewvillegas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glrfilgccqgizafzlzobrbgaoqsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/08a4bf4e9f6e797d8eb62106a7176b83-desc.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/andrewvillegas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glrfilgccqgizafzlzobrbgaoqsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/08a4bf4e9f6e797d8eb62106a7176b83-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/xds/xds_channel_secure.cc:34:
    /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:205:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_credentials_mdelem_array
    /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:206:21: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:208:3: note: type is given name 'grpc_credentials_mdelem_array' for linkage purposes by this typedef declaration
    } grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
      ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/writing.cc:21:
    In file included from /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/context_list.h:26:
    /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:109:15: warning: anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here [-Wnon-c-typedef-for-linkage]
    typedef struct {
                  ^
                   grpc_chttp2_ping_queue
    /Users/andrewvillegas/Developer/flutter_projects/junior_tacos_app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/internal.h:110:52: note: type is not C-compatible due to this default member initializer
      grpc_closure_list lists[GRPC_CHTTP2_PCL_COUNT] = {};
                                                       ^~


Error launching application on iPhone.
```

How can I fix this error? Thank you all!!
--A.V.